# 'Search' feature suggestions for ExtJS 5.1.1

Tags: search, extjs, view, gridpanel

I need some advice for 'Search' feature for ExtJS. I have created a demo-app which has 3 views *(1: Header, 2: Gridpanel, 3: Formpanel)* stays inside of a Viewport, here is a screen-shot:

[image: demo-app]

As you will notice the **Search** field stays in Header view; so is there anyway to configure search functionality from another view, instead of in Gridpanel view.

I have came up to Live-search [[1]](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/examples/grid/live-search-grid.html) and Grid with Filtered [[2]](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/examples/grid/filtered-buffered-store.html) examples but both of them configured within Gridpanel, so they are not suitable with me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So.. any idea? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. so far I found a simple solution for my question but unfortunately it is not the completely suit to me :(

There is a [Filters plugin](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.grid.filters.Filters.html). It's adding a new item to column's sub-menu and searching for data included to Store.

As i told it's not what exactly i am looking for, so i'll try implement it's behaviour to *Search* button via text-field. If anyone will have an opinion; i'll be pleasure...

Here is an example screen-shot:
[image: search]